# Boost not working in django-haystack

Tags: django, django-haystack

I am trying to add boost into my haystack search but sadly not able to. This is my  search_indexes.py.

```
class feedIndex(indexes.SearchIndex, indexes.Indexable):
    text = indexes.EdgeNgramField(document=True, use_template=True)
    feed_text = indexes.EdgeNgramField(model_attr='feed_text',null=True)
    tags = indexes.CharField(model_attr='tags')

    def get_model(self):
        return Feed

    def prepare_feed_text(self, obj):
        return "Feed"

    def prepare(self, obj):
        data = super(feedIndex, self).prepare(obj)
        data['boost'] = 1.5
        return data
```

What else i need to add. Because this i found only this in tutorial. When i run rebult_index i am able to see the boost associated with field in `http://localhost:9200/_search` .
 My search backend is elasticsearch. I have gone through all questions related to this but didnt find useful for me.

Answer (score 2):

Try using `data["_boost"]`. I forget how/why this works for us unfortunately.

Comment: Its not working for me. Whet other changes i have to do other than adding data["_boost"]

Comment: https://github.com/elastic/elasticsearch/issues/4664
Because the index time boost is deprecated, you need to use the old version or write a plugin yourself